# C++: How do I make a VCL component reference itself?

Tags: c++builder, vcl

I'm using C++ Builder in RAD Studio 10.2. I'm not sure if I asked this correctly in the title, but what I'm trying to say is that whenever I use the C++ keyword 'this', it references the Parent of the component that I'm trying to access, but not the component itself.

For example, the code below changes the **Form's** color and font color instead of the **Panel's** color and font color:

```
void __fastcall TForm1::Panel1MouseEnter(TObject *Sender)
{
    this->Color = cl3DLight;
    this->Font->Color = clMaroon;
}
```

Also, if I do the same as above but omit the keyword 'this', it still changes the Form's properties instead of the Panel's (see code below).

```
void __fastcall TForm1::Panel1MouseEnter(TObject *Sender)
{
    Color = cl3DLight;
    Font->Color = clMaroon;
}
```

How would I code this so it accesses the **Panel's** 'Color' and 'Font->Color' instead of the Form's? Thank you.

**Note:** The reason that I haven't just done it as: `Panel1->Color = "cl3DLight";` is because I'm trying to find a way to do it for components created at run-time.

Comment: Does your form have a Panel?  If so, what is the declaration (what is the instance name)?

Comment: Yes. `TPanel *Panel1;` is the declaration, and "Panel1" is the component's name.

Comment: Have you tried: `Panel1->Color = /*...*/;`?

Comment: Yes, sorry, I must've not clarified that in the original post. I'm trying to find a way to do it for components created at run-time, so I can not use the component's instance name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Sender` parameter represents the component that is generating the event. You can typecast that pointer to the proper type in order to access that component's properties.

If you know for sure that everything attached to the event is a `TPanel`, you can typecast it directly (as Remy pointed out in comments below):

```
void __fastcall TForm1::Panel1MouseEnter(TObject *Sender)
{
    TPanel *panel = static_cast<TPanel *>(Sender);
    panel->Color = cl3DLight;
    panel->Font->Color = clMaroon;
}
```

If you're using the same event handler for different control types, you can test for the appropriate type instead:

```
void __fastcall TForm1::Panel1MouseEnter(TObject *Sender)
{
    TPanel *panel = dynamic_cast<TPanel *>(Sender);
    if (panel) 
    {
      panel->Color = cl3DLight;
      panel->Font->Color = clMaroon;
    }
}
```

Comment: Works great! Thanks. 
I found that even a normal cast works, so since I had `TPanel *panel;` already declared, this was my code: `panel = (TPanel *) Sender;`

Comment: That only works if you can be 100% certain that the event has only been assigned to a TPanel. Using `dynamic_cast` protects you in case it's not. Now you've got information on both. :-)

Comment: @awesomedisplayname You should use `static_cast` instead of a C style cast: `panel = static_cast<TPanel *>(Sender);`  Use `static_cast` when you KNOW the type, use `dynamic_cast` when you need to DISCOVER the type

Comment: On the other hand, the `Sender` is typically used only when you have the same event handler assigned to *multiple* controls. If the event handler is assigned to only *a single* control, you could just refer to that control directly instead, eg: `void __fastcall TForm1::Panel1MouseEnter(TObject *Sender) { Panel1->Color = cl3DLight; Panel1->Font->Color = clMaroon; }`

Comment: @RemyLebeau: The poster mentioned (in the Note: in the question) that they were creating the panels at runtime. Thanks for the additional info - Builder is definitely not my area of expertise. :-)

Comment: @KenWhite thanks, I didn't see that Note earlier. Either way, I would still suggest not using `dynamic_cast` in this particular example, since the app knows that it is creating `TPanel` objects, so no need to waste runtime overhead on something it can do at compile-time instead.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: Thanks. I've updated my answer to include both static and dynamic casts. Let me know if I've screwed something up.  :-)